# Google Maps API | Polygon GEOJSON Layer, Will Not Map

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I am attempting to load the three polygons geojson files on the drag-and-drop map, with little success: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/layer-data-dragndrop I have been able to load two similar polygons without issue. I have examined the text of these geojson layers, and I do not see any difference. Any guidance would be appreciated.[Note: I am only allowed to post two URLS, so I have provided one link]

GEOJSON Layers that Do Not Map:

1. https://appliedanalysis.box.com/s/xok9wdhf9psbgnj0z3egfg31nxu7l2kv

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Firefox and Chrome (see [here](http://anatolysukhanov.com/images/firefox.png)). What browser are you using?